# Post a message to the main event loop of a Cocoa application?

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Let's say, in my GUI application (it is portable across OSX/iOS) I have multiple threads that may send notifications to the main application thread. The notifications should be handled within the same context where Cocoa's input events and redraw requests are handled. My goal is to reflect on the screen certain events that come from concurrent threads.

On Windows there is PostMessage(), so what is its analog on OS X and iOS?

`dispatch_async()` seems to be a close candidate for this, however, the documentation says:

> The target queue determines whether the block is invoked serially or
>   concurrently with respect to other blocks submitted to that same
>   queue.

which, honestly, says nothing but creates confusion. Plus it's not clear which of the message queues to use with `dispatch_async` so that the message is handled serially with respect to GUI events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more old-school way to do it on OS X is the NSObject method `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.  I expect that it works on iOS too.

Comment: I love blocks, but somehow I find this method more elegant and better "blending" into ObjC code. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6):

You are right dispatch_async is the way to go. The queue you should look for is the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Got to main thread.");
});
```

Comment: Like I said in the other comment, I love blocks, but somehow I find the method with `performSelectorOnMainThread` more elegant and better "blending" into ObjC code. So I'd accept the other answer, but thanks for yours!